# Generic query to fetch data based on date column in every month in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a task where I need to generate report once in every month let's say 1st of every month. I tried in many ways but every time I need to modify the query in order to get the data for tht particular month.

I used the following query to fetch the data of November:

```
Select * from user 
where m_termination_dt>(sysdate-30) and m_termination_dt<(sysdate).
```

It is giving proper output.( I ran this query on 1st of Dec so subtracted 30days). Here the concern is, as November has 30 days it worked. For Dec I have to minus 31 days instead 30 which is again a human involvement. So is there any way I can write a query without changing the query.

Can anyone please help me with a generic query so that I can automate that query in my system.

Sai.

Comment: What did you try already? You want to create job? You always can use `SYSDATE` to get current date

Comment: Yes. I am aware of that. Syadate can be used for the instance. I want that query to be worked on every month without modifying it again.

Comment: Without more information on the data and the desired output nobody can help you.

Comment: "*Can anyone please help me with a generic query so that I can automate that query in my system.*" I don't see you posted any query to suggest anything.

Comment: In this report a scheduled job or manually u run it with manual date input?

Comment: Sorry all guys. I missed out the query. 
I used the following query to fetch the data of November.

Select * from user where m_termination_dt>(sysdate-30) and m_termination_dt<(sysdate).

It is giving proper output.( I ran this query on 1st of Dec so subtracted 30days).
 Here the concern is, as November has 30 days it worked. For Dec I have to minus 31 days instead 30 which is again a human involvement. 

So is there any way I can write a query without changing the query. If my approach is wrong can anyone please explain the proper approach for my requirement.

Comment: I run this report manually and want to schedule a job if the query works for all the months. @Roy

Answer (score 1):

`Add_months(trunc(sysdate, 'month'), -1)` gives first day of previous month. `Trunc(sysdate, 'month')` gives first day of current month.
So if you run this query you get data from previous month, it does not matter how many days it had:

```
select * from users 
  where add_months(trunc(sysdate, 'month'), -1) <= m_termination_dt 
    and m_termination_dt < trunc(sysdate, 'month')
```

Example:

```
create table users (id number(5), m_termination_dt date);
insert into users values (1, date '2015-11-01');
insert into users values (2, date '2015-11-18');
insert into users values (3, date '2015-11-30');
insert into users values (4, date '2015-12-01');
commit;
```

Output of query:

```
    ID M_TERMINATION_DT
------ ----------------
     1 2015-11-01
     2 2015-11-18
     3 2015-11-30
```